# ¿Como puedo obtener el metodo get() de un map<>?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Esta es la clase la cual tengo el error, el cual map<> no me trae get(). Se que dart no se trae como tal get, pero no se como hacer esa parte, ya que estoy empezando con este lenguaje.

```
class MapStorageInMemory implements MapStorage<Request, CacheEntry>
{
   Map<Request, CacheEntry> cache = new HashMap();

    CacheEntry read(Request req)
    {
        if (!contains(req)) {
            throw new Exception("There is no cached entry for the resource: " + req.getResource());
        } 
        //Este get es el que me da el error
        return this.cache.get(new IdentifiableRequest(req));
    }

    ......
}
```

La clase Request es abstracta y es la que recoge el Map. Es la siguiente:

```
abstract class Request
{
    String getResource();

    String getParameters();

    List<String> getHeaders();
}
```

y la clase CacheEntry es la otra clase que recoge map y es la siguiente:

```
class CacheEntry
{
    DateTime expiration;
    DateTime deadline;
    Response response;

    CacheEntry(Response response, DateTime expiration, DateTime deadline)
    {
        this.response = response;
        this.expiration = expiration;
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }

    int hashCode()
    {
        return this.expiration.hashCode + this.response.hashCode;
    }

    bool equals(Object other)
    {
        if (!(other is CacheEntry)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        CacheEntry entry = other;
        return ((this.expiration == entry.expiration) && (this.response.getStatusCode() == entry.response.getStatusCode())) && (this.response.getBody() == entry.response.getBody());
    }

    String toString()
    {
        return (((("Expiration: " + this.expiration.toString()) + "\nDeadline: ") + this.deadline.toString()) + "\nResponse: ") + new IdentifiableResponse(this.response).toString();
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: que tiene la clase IdentifiableRequest ?

Comment: Igual que la de CacheEntry, es muy parecida, lo que tiene son metodos string y list no tiene más. He intentado hacer esto. **return this.cache[new IdentifiableRequest(req)];** es correcto?

Comment: ahí puse la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de Dart 2.0 puedes omitir la palabra `new`.

En java para acceder a un valor del Map usas el método `get`, en Dart no es necesario, solo basta con indicarle la llave en corchetes.

```dart
this.cache[IdentifiableRequest(req)];
```

También para saber si ese `Map` contiene esa llave puedes usar `containsKey`

```dart
if(this.cache.containtsKey(IdentifiableRequest(req))){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! en el ultimo comentario te habia puesto algo parecido con los corchetes pero no estaba 100% seguro